# Join mysql query with array

Tags: php, mysqli

I have `mysql` table like this

table test

```
| idx|  name  | year | month |
+----+--------+------+-------+
| 1  |  foo-u | 2019 | 1     |
| 2  |  foo-v | 2019 | 2     |
| 3  |  foo-w | 2019 | 3     |
| 4  |  foo-x | 2019 | 1     |
| 5  |  foo-y | 2019 | 2     |
| 6  |  foo-z | 2019 | 3     |
```

and array like this

```
$qty = array("1"=>"42", "4"=>"44", "5"=>"54"); //result from unserialize data
```

how can I join mysql query and `$qty` array with result like this

```
| idx|  name  | year | month |  qty |
+----+--------+------+-------+------+
| 1  |  foo-u | 2019 | 1     |  42  |
| 4  |  foo-x | 2019 | 1     |  44  |
| 5  |  foo-y | 2019 | 2     |  54  |
```

I tried like this

```
<?php
foreach ($qty as $quantity=>$value){
    $product .= $quantity.',';  
}
$produk2 = rtrim($product,',');
$sql = "select * from test where idx in ($produk2)";
?>
```

how can I improve my sql query to inject `$qty` (array value) in my result.
Thanks

Comment: Iterate over query results and append qty data there.

Comment: You can't "join" SQL and php array **using SQL** It has to be done in application (php)

Comment: thats array from another table with serialize data sir, just need some improvement  query select

Comment: "i tried like this" And what exactly was the result?  You don't seem to be doing anything with your query, so I'm not sure how you expect _any_ result.

Comment: $sql = "select * from test where idx in (1,4,5)"; the result without qty sir, just need qty value on my query

Comment: If both tables are in same dataabse - use `JOIN`.

Comment: How are you getting this `$qty = array("1"=>"42", "4"=>"44", "5"=>"54");` ? What is the source?

Comment: from serialize data sir Array ( [1] => 42 [4] => 44 [5] => 54 )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by some unions that build a 'table' with id and corresponding qty, getting from the array

```
select * 
from test 
join 
   (select 1 id, 42 qty 
    union
    select 4 id, 44 qty
    union
    select 5 id, 54 qty) t
using(id)
where idx in (1,4,5)
```

In PHP code

```
$union = [];
foreach ($qty as $quantity=>$value){
    $union[] = "select $quantity id, $value qty";  
}

$produk2 = implode(',', array_keys(qty));
$subquery = implode(' union ', $union);
$sql = "select * from test  join ($subquery) t using(id) where idx in ($produk2)";
```

Comment: Problem is to add values to result array.